# Disabling graph api calls without app secret

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app for sharing images. I wish to integrate **Facebook SDK** in the app.

I am getting user access token from the app. Then this token will be used from the server to download and store images in our server. **I want to make our user's information safe**. I don't want someone else to get user information if they somehow get access to the token from my app.

I have enabled `Require App Secret` in Facebook app dashboard, but when i call the graph api with this access token from my computer, it is giving me a valid response (i.e. I am able to extract user information with the token outside the app without using `app_secret`). However, when I get access to the token of Test users from the developer dashboard and try making calls to the graph API, I am getting:

```
"error": {
  "message": "The access token could not be decrypted",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 190
}
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. So I am doing something wrong when I collect the user's token. Below is my logging in code:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_photos, user_friends"));

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile1, Profile profile) {
                        /**
                         * Getting userId and storing to SP as long
                         */
                        final String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();

                        /**
                         * Getting facebook profilePic, Name and token and storing to SP
                         */
                        String profileImgUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large";
                        final String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                        if (profile == null) return;
                        String name = profile.getName();
                    }
                };
                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("facebook - onCancel", "cancelled");
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Login failed! Please try again.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d("facebook - onError", e.getMessage());
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Login failed! Please try again.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me in finding the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The test user access token mostly wont have the permissions you are expecting. But in that case the error should reflect that. did you check the access token permissions?